# Next.js change from edge function to serverless functions on Netlify

Tags: next.js, netlify

When deploying a Next.js project to Netlify, API routes are deployed as Edge Functions by default.
How can I switch so they are deployed as serverless functions?

I've looked through all the docs I can't find anything about this.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

As of February 2023, that is untrue. Next.js API routes are deployed using Netlify Functions and not Netlify Edge Functions.

Source: https://github.com/netlify/next-runtime#generated-functions

Quoting:

> The Next.js Runtime works by generating three Netlify functions that handle requests that haven't been pre-rendered. These are ___netlify-handler (for SSR and API routes)...